# Slicing a 2D array to match entries from a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

My task today is to properly slice a 2D array so that it matches up correctly with certain entries in a 3D array. For example, I have the 3D array below:

```
[[[  1.06103295e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   1.06103295e+02   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.06103295e+02]]

 [[  5.09297818e+05   5.09296818e+05   5.09296818e+05]
 [  5.09296818e+05   5.09297818e+05   5.09296818e+05]
 [  5.09296818e+05   5.09296818e+05   5.09297818e+05]]

[[  5.09297818e+05   5.09296818e+05   5.09296818e+05]
 [  5.09296818e+05   5.09297818e+05   5.09296818e+05]
 [  5.09296818e+05   5.09296818e+05   5.09297818e+05]]

[[  1.06103295e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
[  0.00000000e+00   1.06103295e+02   0.00000000e+00]
[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.06103295e+02]]]
```

Using the "numpy.reshape" command, I changed it a 2D array with dimensions (12, 3).

```
[[  1.06103295e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.06103295e+02   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.06103295e+02]
 [  5.09297818e+05   5.09296818e+05   5.09296818e+05]
 [  5.09296818e+05   5.09297818e+05   5.09296818e+05]
 [  5.09296818e+05   5.09296818e+05   5.09297818e+05]
 [  5.09297818e+05   5.09296818e+05   5.09296818e+05]
 [  5.09296818e+05   5.09297818e+05   5.09296818e+05]
 [  5.09296818e+05   5.09296818e+05   5.09297818e+05]
 [  1.06103295e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.06103295e+02   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.06103295e+02]]
```

Now how do I slice this so that I get entries that are in the same form as above?

For example, I already sliced one of the entries like such:

```
M11 = myarrayname[0:3, 0:3]
```

and I got the result:

```
[[ 106.10329539    0.            0.        ]
 [   0.          106.10329539    0.        ]
 [   0.            0.          106.10329539]]
```

Notice that this is the same as one of the blocks from the 3D array above (minus the scientific notation). How do I keep slicing the entries to get the other 3 blocks from the 3D array above?

When I tried to do M12 = myarrayname[4:6, 4:6],

I simply got an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use np.reshape again (if `A` is your array):

```
B = np.reshape(A, (12, 3))
C = np.reshape(B, (4, 3, 3))
```

But if you'd rather select the arrays by yourself, then:

```
M11 = B[0:3, 0:3]
M12 = B[3:6, 0:3]
M13 = B[6:9, 0:3]
M14 = B[9:12, 0:3]
```